# ASP.Net BoilerPlate - Application Layer and Web Layer

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

I am using the [ASP.Net BoilerPlate](https://aspnetboilerplate.com/), a starting point for new modern web applications using best practices and popular tools. I am making an MVC, Web API, single page web application.

But I have noticed that based on the documentation that the Nlayer is based like bellow:[image] where you can see it better on the link (https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/NLayer-Architecture)

What is strange for me is that the management of DTOs and DTO mappings are made on the Application layer, I tough it would be made on the Web Layer on the ASP.Net **MVC Controller** or on the **Web API Controllers**, that would call the Application Layer and from the Controller it would make the mapping of DTOs.

But it seems that the **MVC Controllers** are not even used according to it's example linked on the documentation (https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1043326/A-Multi-Tenant-SaaS-Application-With-ASP-NET-MVC-A).

If I make the DTO mapping in the Controller and make the controller Application layer responsable only to call the Service and retrieve Entities is not a better practice ?

Comment: The DTO in the application layer has to do with the back end data representation.  There will then be mappings made in the controller which convert the data from the application layer models to the view models for consumption in the front end.

Comment: So it would need to have another data transformation on the controller, from DTO to ViewModel ? And strangely the Controllers are almost never used on the example from CodeProject that is referenced on the documentation. This is something really strange for me.

Comment: Ideally the controller actions are pretty simple:  Get data (dtos), map data to VMs, return it.  I like to keep as little logic in there as possible, but sometimes they can get pretty messy.